# Is a comparison on monotonic count integer safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I know in a multithread environment doing this is not safe:

```
if (some_var > 0) {
  // Do something.
}
```

Because when comparing, there might be another thread changing the value.

What if some_var is a counter. That is, it can only increment, never decreases. Then is following operation thread safe?

```
if(some_counter >0) {
   // Do something.
}
```

Also does it make difference if some_counter is either byte, or int32, int64?

Comment: If you're worried about thread safety, *always* use protection. Mutexes, semaphores, locks or atomics.

Comment: From the perspective of C++, both cases are the very same → data race = undefined behavior. Data type doesn't matter.

Comment: No. Every thread may have its own local cached value. You need to use atomic variables or put proper memory barrier to ensure that updates are visible globally.

Comment: And what if one thread fetches the value of `some_counter` when it's equal to zero, then the thread is preempted and a new thread runs which increases the value of `some_counter`, and the first thread runs again. The value previously fetched will be wrong, and the condition will be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What if some_var is a counter. That is, it can only increment, never decreases. Then is following operation thread safe?

No it isn't. Incrementing isn't an atomic operation.

> Also does it make difference if some_counter is either byte, or int32, int64?

It doesn't really make a difference.

You should rather use a `std::atomic<int>` (or other template parameter type) to guarantee thread safety.

Comment: Does C++ atomic guarantee the writes are visible to the other threads or the memory order has to be changed?

Comment: @Oblivion Suppose you have an atomic counter initialized with 0. If you increment this counter _n_ times in multiple threads, the result is guaranteed to be _n_ even with  the weakest, i.e., _relaxed_ order.

Comment: @DanielLangr thanks. some other SO question had made me confused.